# Activity Flows A->B->C->A in android

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

**Suppose I have 3 activities: A, B and C.**

- A: Home Activity
- B: Information gather Activity
- C: Information display Activity

**My desired flow goes like:**

- A triggers B to gather information.
- When B ends, C will get the information and display.
- A->B->C->A.
- When C ends, it should go back to A. (this is never a problem as I will B: finish())

---

**My first attempt:** (Failed due to I do not want to see the A after B, even for few miliseconds)

1. A triggers B to gather information. (startActivityAsResult)
2. B pass result to A, and B :`finish()`.  (onActivityResult)
3. Then A triggers C to display. (startActivity)

**My second attempt:** (Succeed but I'm thinking is there a better way despite this?)

1. A triggers B to gather information. (startActivity)
2. B triggers C, and B :`finish()`.  (startActivity)

---

**Questions:**

Is there any alternative way (which is simpler/direct) of defining the *sequence* of navigation flows like i see `taskBuilder` with `nextIntent()` API?

Comment: I think your second attempt is better one than first one. And I feel that's the better way.

Comment: I thought there would be a ready and simpler API for working out the flows :)

Comment: IMHO, your second attempt seems the way to go. It easier, cleaner and simpler to follow as well!

Comment: possible duplicate of [android go back to first screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337567/android-go-back-to-first-screen)

Comment: `I thought there would be a ready and simpler API for working out the flows`.  There is.  You just used it! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Activity C on back button press clear the backstack and navigate to A

```
 @Override 
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    onBackPressed();

}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }

    public void onBackPressed() {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(C.this,A.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear the backstack
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
return;
   }
```

A to B To C

In your activity back stack you will have C at the top, next B and next A.

When you press back button in C, activity C is popped from stack, destroyed and the previous activity B takes focus. So if you wish to navigate to A from C ,clear the back stack , navigate to A and finish the current activity.

Comment: Hii @RaghuNandan i can also call the Finish() method In B at the time when i am triggering C from it .So i dont need the Intent.

Comment: yup you can do that. But you said you need an alternative so i provided one.

Comment: @Raghunandan actually I was asking if there's an alternative for the flow like having a taskBuilder to specify the sequence of activities :) not for the intent.

Comment: you need to decide the sequence of activities. A to B to C or A to C. It depends on how you design you app.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to make it impossible for the user to use the back button to get into activities that have already been "used up," yes?  Try modifying the activity tags in your AndroidManifest.xml using something like the following:

```
<activity
    android:name="yourpackagename.yourappname.YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/your_app_title"
    android:noHistory="true" >
```

Once you add the `noHistory` attribute, the activity in question is yanked from the activity history, and you'll be able to force your user to go only forwards as your intents describe.

Comment: Nope, that was not I meant :) User may back at anytime. If B succeed to gather information, then it should flows to C. But if B failed to gather information, A is the only flow it goes, but not C.

Comment: alright at least I learned something from you, you have d credit :) +1

Comment: Glad my inability to comprehend English produced a useful result. ;)